# How do I hide the buttons to the right of the opened file tabs in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is an image showing the  buttons to the right of the opened file tabs:
[image: image showing the buttons]

What setting is used to hide those? They take up too much horizontal space.

Comment: these commands are placed in the `navigation` group of the `editor/title` menu but should be placed in the `3_open` group

Comment: I don't understand....

Comment: The buttons are created in the wrong group of the menu. Create an issue to add a setting to put these buttons in a different group, for the different extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [VSCode 1.72](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_72#_hide-actions-from-tool-bars) you can right-click an icon and choose to hide it from the context menu:

[image]

If you like the buttons in general and just dislike their position (because it makes [editor tabs jump around](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115136)), you can move them down to the breadcrumb bar, where they are smaller and do not take up that much space:

[image: icons in breadcrumb bar]

This is done using the [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) extension with the following configuration:

```
"customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".tabs-and-actions-container": {
        "background-color": "inherit",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions": {
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "100%",
        "right": "0px",
        "height": "22px !important",
        "z-index": "1",
        "background-color": "inherit",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item": {
        "margin-right": "3px !important",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item a": {
        "font-size": "13px",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item .codicon": {
        "width": "13px",
        "height": "13px",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .tab:last-child": {
        "margin-right": "0 !important",
    },
    ".title.tabs.show-file-icons": {
        "overflow": "unset !important",
    },
}
```

This solution is theme-independent, so it should work for all colour combinations. The background color for the buttons is always the same as the background color of the tab bar. If you use only one static theme, you could hard-code the `background-color` for the `.tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions` selector to the exact color of the breadcrumb bar for a more seamless design. However, this does not work when switching themes.

The only drawback to this solution is that the buttons overflow the rightmost breadcrumb information, but I'm fine with that.